# Which is a better time complexity?

Tags: time-complexity

I have to pick out which operations have a better worst case time complexity on an AVL tree than a BST. I have established that the time complexity for each operation is the same depending on the tree...

The worst case time complexity for an AVL tree is...

```
Insert - O(log(n))
Remove - O(log(n))
Search - O(log(n))
```

The worst case time complexity for a BST is....

```
Insert - O(height)
Remove - O(height)
Search - O(height)
```

So is O(log(n)) a better time complexity than O(height)?

Comment: Tell us, what is the height of a BST as a function of n?

Comment: @DaveS it would be O(n)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Big O(h) vs. Big O(logn) in trees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258114/big-oh-vs-big-ologn-in-trees)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The worst case time complexity on a BST for insert, remove, and search is `O(n)`, where `n` is the number of nodes in the BST. You can trigger this worst case by inserting nodes into a BST in an order such that the BST is essentially a linked list (e.g. first insert 1, then insert 2, then insert 3, and so on... you will end up with a BST that looks like 1 -> 2 -> 3...).

`O(log(n))` is a better time complexity than `O(n)`.

Comment: So an AVL tree has a better worst case for all 3 operations? (insert, remove, and search)

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The AVL tree is self-balancing, meaning that no matter what order you add nodes to it, its maximum height will remain `O(log(n))`. You cannot trigger the linked-list worst case scenario like in a BST.

Answer (score 0):

`O(log(n))` is best case scenario for `O(height)`. Height of your binary tree can be any integer between `log(n)` and `n` where `n` denotes the number of nodes.

For example if you have a BST where each node has only right child, it is the same as if it were a linked list, thus having `O(n)` worst case complexity for all three operations.

On the other hand AVL is self-**balancing** binary search tree, meaning every two sub-trees from any node have the same depth (height) +- constant. That means you are approximately halving the values at every step, thus getting `O(log(n))` complexity, which is also your `O(height)` complexity.

Answer (score 0):

An AVL tree is basically a height balanced BST.
If you consider a full AVL tree, log n (AVL tree) > log n (BST).
-> where n is the number of nodes.

whereas when you consider O (height), it'll be the same in both the AVL and BST.
3
  \
    5
      (BST)
height = 2 , n = 2

```
  3  
 / \  
2   5  
       (AVL)
```

height = 2, n = 3